# Memory Error - while iterating Execute Package Tasks Multiple times

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a developed a solution where I have the below flow to execute for Parallel Processing.

Launch Package - Pick the Scheduled Job and Triggers Tasks to Parent Package based on certain criteria’s 
Parent Package - Has different flows to execute tasks for Remote and Table creation
Child Packages – Where based on the Task assigned to Parent Package and flows identified it triggers the execution

We have Parent to Child execution up to levels and vice versa. The entire flow execute within a for each loop where we have Execute Package Task used to call different child packages within a Child Package and return the updated values through Variables.

The solution works fine for 20- 30 attempts and then gets stuck at one the Child Packages for long time and the error that we receive in the Progress Tab is as below. This does not stuck at one static place its happens randomly at any Execution Package Task.

Error 0x80070008 while executing package from project reference package \"pkg.dtsx\". Not enough storage is available to process this command.
this is the error message it gets triggered

The system on which I am running this has a RAM of 512 GB and 2 Processors.

Can you please help us identify on how we can resolve this issue and move ahead to make the solution working.

Comment: Is this being run in visual studio? It could be all the windows that are being opened that would not happen when run from Agent

Comment: Yes this is being run from Visual Studio, when its run through Agent it fails for reason 'Unexpected Termination'